# how to wait till a button is getting clicked in selenium webdriver c#?

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-firefoxdriver

In firefox browser, requirement is to wait until a element(button) is getting clicked.
How can we achieve it?

`wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id(""))` is not working here.

Comment: What do you mean "is getting clicked"?

Comment: You will have to write your own ExpectedCondition. I can help you. What is the effect when the button is clicked? Does the button disappear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can always wait for visibility of element which appears after the button is clicked..

```
new WebDriverWait(driver,60).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("id_of_the_new_element")));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the button triggers, but you can try something like:

```
var buttonIsClicked = false;

while (!buttonIsClicked)
{
    // check something that can tell you if your button action was performed
    if (conditionsMet) buttonIsClicked = true;    
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
By element= By.xpath("//body/div[3]/div[1]/div/a/span");
WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
WebElement var = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(element));
if(var.isDisplayed())
{
    var.click();
}
```